# Blocked AioHTTP webserver when calling AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, aiohttp

I am trying to write a webserver in Python with aiohttp that receives a post request and calls a aws lambda function with boto3. Everything is working already, but everytime the webserver receives the post request that calls the lambda function it gets blocked from executing any other request until the lambda function returns.

webserver.py

```py
from aiohttp import web
from lambdaProcess import invoke_lambda
import json
import asyncio

PORT = 8000
HOST = "0.0.0.0"

routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@routes.get('/healthcheck')
async def test(request):
    print(request)
    return web.Response(text="Healthy")


@routes.post('/send')
async def lambdaRequest(request):
    print(request)
    if request.body_exists:
        body = await request.post()
        code = body.get("code")
        simulation_type = body.get("simulation_type")

        start_date = body.get("start_date")
        end_date = body.get("end_date")

        lambda_response = invoke_lambda(code, simulation_type, start_date, end_date)

        result = json.loads(lambda_response['Payload'].read().decode())

        return web.Response(text=result)


app = web.Application()
app.add_routes(routes)
#web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)

async def start_app():
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, host=HOST, port=PORT)
    await site.start()
    print(f"Serving up on {HOST}:{PORT}")
    return runner, site

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
runner, site = loop.run_until_complete(start_app())
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt as err:
    loop.run_until_complete(runner.cleanup())
```

lambdaProcess.py

```py
import boto3
import json
import sys


def invoke_lambda(code, simulation_type, start_date, end_date):
    """Invoke Lambda function using boto3
    Parameters:
    - bucket: Answer code sent by student
    - dataset: dataset name used by the answer code
    """

    # Set Boto3 Lambda Client
    client = boto3.client('lambda')

    # Dictionary to be posted on the lambda event
    payload = {
        "code": code,
        "simulation_type": simulation_type,
        "start_date": start_date,
        "end_date": end_date
    }

    response = client.invoke(
        FunctionName='teste',
        InvocationType='RequestResponse',
        LogType='Tail',
        Payload=json.dumps(payload)
    )
    return response
```

Thanks.